# If $f$ is continuous at a point prove that there exists some neighbourhood so that $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ in that neighbourhood.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Use the definition of continuity and limits to prove that:
if $x$ is continuous at a point $x_0$ and $f(x_0)>0$ then there exist a neighbourhood around $x_0$ such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ in this neighbourhood.

I know both the definition of continuity and limits, and intuitively this makes sense, but I am still not able to prove this precisely.

Comment: @BenjaminMoss  Neighbourhood is the British spelling; neighborhood is the American spelling.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I know that, just like 'armour' and 'colour' etc. No worries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the limit of $f$ at $x_0$ is $f(x_0)$, since $f$ is continuous. Since $f(x_0)>0$, $\frac{f(x_0)}{4}>0$. By definition of limits of functions, there exits a number $m>0$, such that, for all $x$ in the interval $(x_0-m,x_0+m)$, $f(x)$ is in the $\left(f(x_0)-\frac{f(x_0)}{4},f(x_0)+\frac{f(x_0)}{4}\right)$, which consist of positive numbers.

Sorry about the writing style, im very new to this site.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. I have edited your post to improve readability, here is  a [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/144766) tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Take $I=({f(x_0)\over 2},{3f(x_0)\over 2})$, $f^{-1}(I)$ is such a neighborhood.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "neighborhood". Certainly this is an open set containing $x_0$, but there is no guarantee that this is a ball. Consider $f(x) = x^2$, then this would yield two disconnected intervals.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, you can choose $\varepsilon :=\frac{f(x_0)}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Try to make a picture of the situation and find the $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ from the definitions. It will help with thinking of a way to construct a proof.